# Xamarin Fail to initialize device

Tags: android, xamarin

Im a freshman of Xamarin. Pls help.
I just followed the guideline of Xamarin

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/

until the step of 31

Finally, we can test our application by deploying it to an Android emulator. If you have not yet configured your emulator, please see Xamarin Android Player for setup instructions. In this example, we have installed the Nexus 4 (KitKat) (Android 4.4.2, API Level 19) virtual device and we have started it from the Xamarin Android Player Device Manager console:

I run the Xamarin Android player to test this quick start, it has a problem,
I got a message: Fail to initialize device
I google it with 0 answer

suck this account need a 10 reputation to upload a picture , how I can get the reputation?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your installed devices.
When I installed Xamarin Android Player no devices were downloaded automatically. You need download and install all you needed devices manually.

[image]

Comment: I downloaded, but when I run these device. the Xamarin Android Player shows that Failed to initialize device Nexusxxx something, by the way , what is the version of ur Oracle VM? and can u run a 64 bit OS on the VM? coz I just have the options of 32 bit OS, I think the VM might be the problem.

Comment: I have 64bit machine and XAP also 64bit supported.

Answer (score 0):

For now it's better to use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) but in the future Xamarin Android Player will be a good alternative too,

if you want [Xamarin Android Player](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-player/) for now, install the latest version and download manually a device, Make it start and try again.

Comment: Im a new Xamarin Android player, and I had tried to install and reinstall this crap many times, the problem didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be in enabling virtual technology in the bios.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. 
My solution was to enable
I had to go to My 'Network Connections' in my control panel, found the Connection named 'Virtual Box Host-Only Network', right clicked it and went to the properties and CHECKED the option 'VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridge Networking Driver' and reconnected. This fixed it for me.

[image]